# Django Registration Redux Login

Tags: python, django, django-registration

I am using Django-registration-redux and its templates for my website authentication.By default, users should Login to my website by providing username and password. In my case, I want users to Login with their Emails instead of usernames. But While registering, users should provide usernames, so I don't want to change the default registration form.

I have seen previous StackOverflow questions, which manipulate registration forms by using `RegistrationView` class. I don't want to change registration form. How to do this?